# How to gets parameters from service to activity 

Tags: android, design-patterns, service

I wrote some code that activity starts a service to get some text from URL, after the service done I want to get this parameters to activity back.

My code looks like this:

```
public class splash extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

  private Context context; 
  private ProgressDialog Dialog; 
  protected config app;

  public splash(Context context){
      this.context=context;
      Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
  }

  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      //starts service number activite
      Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
      serviceIntent.setAction("services.conServise");
      context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

I dont want to use global parameters and not a singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the `Service` from your `Activity`, what you want is a [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). It will bind your service to a variable, and you will be able to use that in the `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for communicating  between activity ad service.Create a Custom BroadcastReceiver to send data back from service to Activity.see this tutorial for how we communicate between service and Activity using Custom BroadcastReceiver

[Custom Intents and Broadcasting with Receivers](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)

[Communication between service and activity – Part 1](http://androidexperinz.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/communication-between-service-and-activity-part-1/)

Comment: can i just create an object service and after that just call the paramter of service class? like MyService.url? or its bad?

Comment: maybe possible but proper way is communicate between Service and Activity using BroadcastReceiver